# Does AspnetCore 2.0 uses TLS 2.0 when we upload file to Azure file storage using Microsoft Stoage (CloudStorageAccount)

Tags: ssl, azure-storage-files, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I am using Aspnetcore 2.0 MVC with entityframework. I am uploading file to Azure file storage service suing Microsoft Azure storage service. Thanks to earlier post in this blog.

Want to know whether this uses TLS 2.0 to upload files to Azure, if yes , then how can i identify ?

Answer (score 0):

> Want to know whether this uses TLS 2.0 to upload files to Azure, if yes , then how can i identify ?

For a simple way, you could use [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to check the supported SSL version on your server side.

Here, I checked my file storage host name: `brucchstorage.file.core.windows.net`.

[image]

**Note:** The latest TLS version supported by file storage server side is TLS1.2, and the TLS1.3 is not supported for now.

For uploading files to azure file storage, you may leverage the client library [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) which internally uses [File Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) against `http(s)://<account>.file.core.windows.net` host name.

In summary, the supported maximum version of TLS on the Azure file storage server side is TLS1.2, so the maximum TLS version between your application and file storage server is TLS1.2. Details you could leverage the network analyzer (e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865),etc.) to parse the headers of SSL/TLS packets and show you the detailed info.